# Akka.Remote - cannot send messages to remote actor after dissassociation

Tags: akka.net

I am using Akka.Remote to communicate between a server-side service application and multiple desktop client applications. The clients send a request message to the server (using Akka.net) and waits for the server to reply with a response message. The client applications are transient, meaning that they often connect to the server, stay connected for some time, disconnect and then reconnect again.

The problem I encountered is that sometimes when a client disconnects from the server actor (by shutting down its `ActorSystem`) and then reconnects back to the server, it does not receive any replies from the server for some time. After a few minutes the communication works without any problems. I found out that this issue occurs when the server sends a reply to a client that has disconnected during the request and is no longer reachable. The server cannot deliver the response message and it somehow marks the client endpoint as invalid.

In the log (on the server side) I am getting the following messages when the client is disconnected.

```
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6151 received AutoReceiveMessage <Terminated>: [akka.tcp://qb@client:8090/user/qb] - ExistenceConfirmed=True  ServerActor
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6550 Stopped  Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor
[ INFO] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6550 Quarantined address [akka.tcp://qb@client:8090] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.  Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6725 Stopped  Akka.Remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6725 no longer watched by [akka://myservice/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3a%2f%2fqb%40client%3a8090-2]  Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6725 Disassociated [akka.tcp://myservice@server:8081] <- akka.tcp://qb@client:8090  Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6725 Stopped  Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter
```

And then when the client attempts to reconnect, I get:

```
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:15.5883 ConnectResponse [akka.tcp://qb@client:8090/user/qb]  ServerActor
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0467 Started (Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor)  Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0467 Stopped  Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor
[ WARN] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0467 AssociationError [akka.tcp://myservice@server:8081] -> akka.tcp://qb@client:8090: Error [Invalid address: akka.tcp://qb@client:8090] []  Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter
[ INFO] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0467 Quarantined address [akka.tcp://qb@client:8090] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.  Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0643 Stopped  Akka.Remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0711 no longer watched by [akka://myservice/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3a%2f%2fqb%40client%3a8090-4]  Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0711 Disassociated [akka.tcp://myservice@server:8081] -> akka.tcp://qb@client:8090  Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0711 Stopped  Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0867 received AutoReceiveMessage <Terminated>: [akka://myservice/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3a%2f%2fqb%40client%3a8090-4] - ExistenceConfirmed=True  Akka.Remote.EndpointManager
[DEBUG] 2016-01-21 13:05:16.0867 Terminated [akka.tcp://qb@client:8090/user/qb]  ServerActor
```

I suspect that this behavior is a feature of Akka.net, however, I need to implement my system so that clients can disconnect and then reconnect back to the server without the need to wait. Is there any way to disable the quarantine mechanism or to gracefully close the client endpoint on the server so that the client endpoint doesn't get quarantined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ INFO] 2016-01-21 13:04:58.6550 Quarantined address [akka.tcp://qb@client:8090] is still unreachable or has not been restarted. Keeping it quarantined.` - that says it all. The node was quarantined which requires a restart of the actor system.

However, IMHO - just upgrade to Akka.NET 1.0.6, which we released on Monday. We made the remoting policy manager much less brittle than it has been historically.

Comment: Thank you @Aaronontheweb. Do I need to restart the actor system on the server side or the client side? Or both?

Comment: You'd need to restart the actor system on the other end of the connection - so if the server is reporting that it quarantined the client, you'd need to restart the client.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb Is this still a valid scenario? It's strange that I have to restart `ActorSystem` after I loose network connection.
If so, is there any way to circumvent this default behavior?

Comment: @Hav still valid. If you get quarantined, it means one of your two actor systems is corrupted because system messages failed to get delivered. If I tried to subscribe to a deathwatch for a remote actor, but that subscription never gets delivered and thus can't work, what's the right thing to do? Reboot or wait forever for a message that will never come?

TBH though, I don't see this very often - usually only when someone has a screwed up configuration or there's problems with bleeding edge updates to .NET Core sockets / DotNetty.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb We have a scenario when the connection is down between two nodes (network is down). When we restore the connection after ActorSystem was quarantined, we are screwed. We have no other option but to restart the ActorSystem, nevertheless, it was just a temporary network partitioning, and now everything is fine. 

Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't see any scenario when it is safe to use Akka.Remote directly. Maybe when two processes reside on the same machine, but it is not the point.